# App is crashing on app launch after migrating Android Gradle plugin from 3.3.3 to 3.6.4 : Didn't find application class on Dex path list

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

App is crashing on app launch after migrating  Android Gradle plugin from 3.3.3 to 4.0.1 : Didn't find application class on Dex path list

Even tried to migrate from 3.3.3 to 3.6.4, still its failing
Gradle version: 5.6.4

Error Logs:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test.app.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~2UwRWIWzJ9c2aanqbQu2rA==/com.test-Lj45TaB1g1EDt5rRrgr3fA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~2UwRWIWzJ9c2aanqbQu2rA==/com.mint-Lj45TaB1g1EDt5rRrgr3fA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~2UwRWIWzJ9c2aanqbQu2rA==/com.mint-Lj45TaB1g1EDt5rRrgr3fA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]

All the cache clean up, rebuild steps tried but nothing is working. Is it something about packaging apk or some meta-inf related behaviour changes on the AGP? Any help on this will be really appreciated
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Check once instant run enabled or not. If enabled disable it. Also, try clean and build or restart with reset cache Menu File -> Invalidates.

Comment: Thanks, I tried those, its not working